# Mac login not working after initial screen

Tags: macbook-pro

Suddenly my MacBook Air won't accept my password.  When I restart, the first screen offers to let me login with my username and symbol, and accepts my password, but then opens a screen giving me the option to logon as Guest or a fill in the blank Name, and if I put on my name and password it doesn't work. I can't get past this except as guest so can't get in the Apple menu. Any idea what is going on and what I can do ? Have tried restarting, turning off, logging in as guest, and still locked out.

Comment: Is FileVault enabled? It can cause some login issues

Comment: Yes. From the beginning 3 years ago. It's required at work

Answer (score 1):

May be the trash became full and not enough memory to bootup. You try boot in target mode , mount the disk in another mac machine and clear the trash.
or 
In Recovery mode open "Disk utility -> repair disk" may help.